# How to implement Singleton Banners with Mopub on Android?

Tags: android, view, singleton, ads, mopub

Mopub recommends using Singleton approach to displaying banners so the same ad view can be reused in different screens. See [here](https://dev.twitter.com/mopub/ad-formats/banners-singleton) for article.

Unfortunately, they have *no* examples or any sample code. Any suggestions on how to implement this on Android?

Currently, every activity in my app has this view in layout xml

```
<com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView
   android:id="@+id/ad"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="@dimen/mopubHeight"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
/>
```

Then in code, every activity loads ad into view.

```
_ad = (MoPubView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
_ad.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.mopub_id));
_ad.loadAd();
```

How do I convert this to singleton approach? I want to do this without converting all the activities in my app into fragments and keeping the ad view fragment in place. This would require that I refactor the entire app and would take too much time. Are there any other ideas?